# google maps engine java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I wanna use google maps engine in my java project to get distance between two locations. I developed a hello world code just to test the engine, but I got strange error when I run my project.

here is my code

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.MapsEngine;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.MapsEngineRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.model.Feature;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.model.FeaturesListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.model.GeoJsonPoint;

import java.io.IOException;

/** Java "Hello, world!" example using the client library */
public class ComputeDistance {

static final String SAMPLE_TABLE_ID = "12421761926155747447-06672618218968397709";
static final String PUBLIC_API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

// This request initializer will ensure the API key is sent with every HTTP request.
MapsEngineRequestInitializer apiKeyInitializer =
    new MapsEngineRequestInitializer(PUBLIC_API_KEY);

MapsEngine engine = new MapsEngine.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, null)
    .setMapsEngineRequestInitializer(apiKeyInitializer)
    .setApplicationName("Google-MapsEngineSample/1.0")
    .build();

readFeaturesFromTable(engine);
 }

 public static void readFeaturesFromTable(MapsEngine me) throws IOException {
// Query the table for offices in WA that are within 100km of Perth.
FeaturesListResponse featResp =  me.tables().features().list(SAMPLE_TABLE_ID)
    .setVersion("published")
    .setWhere("State='WA' AND ST_DISTANCE(geometry,ST_POINT(115.8589,-31.9522)) < 100000")
    .execute();

for (Feature feat : featResp.getFeatures()) {
  System.out.println(
      "Properties: " + feat.getProperties().toString() + "\n\t" +
      "Name: " + feat.getProperties().get("Fcilty_nam") + "\n\t" +
      "Geometry Type: " + feat.getGeometry().getType());

  if (feat.getGeometry() instanceof GeoJsonPoint)  {
    GeoJsonPoint point = (GeoJsonPoint) feat.getGeometry();
    System.out.println("\t" +
        "Longitude: " + point.getCoordinates().get(0) + ", " +
        "Latitude: " +  point.getCoordinates().get(1));
  } else {
    System.out.println("Only points are expected in this table!");
    return;
  }
}
 }
}
```

here is the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/json/AbstractGoogleJsonClient
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 19 more
```

Comment: It seems you have maybe some of the dependencies out of order. If so, they might not be available when compiled... Did you add the jar file and if so move it ahead of others in the class path.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't physically paste the jar files to the system "ext" library.